# The homotopy type of the simplicial space obtained by free adding degeneracies to a semi-simplicial space

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, simplicial-stuff

Let $\text{sTop},\text{ssTop}$ denote the categories of simplicial, semi-simplicial spaces respectively. There is a functor $E:\text{ssTop}\rightarrow \text{sTop}$ that is left adjoint to the forgetful functor $E:\text{sTop}\rightarrow \text{ssTop}$.

Given a semi-simplicial space $X_{\bullet}$, $EX_{\bullet}$ is the simplicial space with $p$-simplices $$EX_{p}:=\coprod_{\beta :[p]\twoheadrightarrow [q]}(X_{q},\beta ),$$ where $[n]$ denotes the linearly-ordered set $\{0<1<\cdots < n\}$.
The simplicial data of $EX_{\bullet}$ is as follows. Let $\gamma :[r]\rightarrow [p]$ be a map of finite linearly ordered sets. For a surjection $\beta: [p]\twoheadrightarrow [q]$, factor $\beta\circ \gamma : [r]\rightarrow [q]$ as the composition $\gamma_{1}\circ \beta_{1}: [r]\rightarrow [q]$, where $\beta_{1}:[r]\twoheadrightarrow [s]$ is a surjection and $\gamma_{1}:[s]\hookrightarrow [q]$ is an injection, and define $\gamma : EX_{p}\rightarrow EX_{r}$ on $(X_{q},\beta )$ to be the map $\gamma_{1}^{*}:(X_{q},\beta )\rightarrow (X_{s}, \beta_{1})\subset EX_{r}$  (more details are given on page 3 of Ebert and Randal-Williams' *Semi-simplicial spaces*, arXiv:[1705.03774](https://arxiv.org/abs/1705.03774)).

Is it known if (or under which conditions) the thick geometric realization $\Vert EX_{\bullet}\Vert$ and the thin geometric realization $\vert EX_{\bullet}\vert$ are weakly equivalent? If the $p$-simplices $X_{p}$ are empty for $p>2$, then the thick and thin geometric realizations are weakly equivalent by directly checking that the degeneracy maps $s_{i}:EX_{p}\rightarrow EX_{p+1}$ are cofibrations for all $i$ and $p$ (in this case, $EX_{\bullet}$ is what Segal calls a "[good](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/geometric+realization+of+simplicial+topological+spaces#relation_between_fat_and_ordinary_geometric_realization)" simplicial space, so its thick and thin geometric realizations are weakly equivalent).

Comment: The degeneracy maps are always just the inclusion of some terms in the disjoint union, so are cofibrations. So $EX_\bullet$ is always good.